# Изменение Location в iOS

Tags: ios, геолокация

Поступила задача создать программу, чтобы можно было указывать свое местоположение вручную. Чтобы карты Apple, Google и т.п. видели ту геопозицую, которую я указывал в мною созданной программе в ручную.

В чем вопрос: Получиться ли это разработать, и можно немного алгоритма? просто объясните.. и возможно ли это сделать без джейлбрейка?

***UPD:*** Аналог такой программы имеется в Андроид: Location Spoofer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, такое сделать нельзя!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Подделать собственное настоящее местоположение, полученное от GPS-модуля нельзя, но что мешает вносить правку в значения Double полученных координат? :)

В любом случае в приложении можно формировать файл с "неким местоположением" в правильном формате (например, KML, KMZ или др., в том числе использовать и собственный уникальный формат), которое можно отправить на другое устройство и открыть в совместимом приложении.

Подобная логика реализована в приложении MAPSME - тыкаешь на карту, появляется точка с именем и координатами, нажимаешь "Поделиться" и отправляешь по e-mail либо через мессенджеры.

[image: Mapsme - поделиться местом]

На втором устройстве при открытии полученного файла открывается web-страница, на которой эта точка отображена на карте, плюс предлагается открыть данное местоположение в приложении и/или установить его, если его нет в телефоне/планшете.

Как пользователь MAPSME в течение многих лет я имел иногда заморочки с передачей и открытием точек, но обычно такие проблемы решались закрытием и повторным открытием точки/приложения. Чаще всего все успешно передается и получается (более 90% случаев).

Аналогично можно сделать для гуглокарт и других каких-нибудь.